# How to run 2 Apache on Windows

Tags: apache-2.2

I currently have xampp running on my box. I would like to add another apache to balance the load for my download serving.

Is it possible and what are the steps required to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: I might be missing something here, but how does this help balance load? As there is only one set of hardware, after all...

Answer (score 1):

You already have Apache running under XAMPP, so if you want another copy of Apache running on the server then you need to run this on a different port ( an separate install locations etc)

However running two copies of Apache on one server is going to have no impact on your load, your still using a single piece of hardware, having 2 installs of Apache will make no difference. If you want to do load balancing, you will need two pieces of hardware.